# How to add left arrow between two tables?

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx

How can I add an arrow between two tables?

[image]

```
    \documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{booktabs}

        \begin{document}

    \begin{table*}[!htb]

    \large\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.1pt}
     \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{First Table}
    \label{tab:first_table}

   \medskip
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Start} & \textbf{Interval Time} & \textbf{Destination} \\
\midrule
Zone 1 & $483$ & Zone 2 \\
Zone 1 & $848$ & Zone 3  \\
Zone 1 & $121$ & Zone 4  \\
Zone 2 & $13$ & Zone 3 \\
  Zone 1 & $121$ & Zone 4  \\
Zone 2 & $13$ & Zone 3 \\
  Zone 1 & $121$ & Zone 4  \\
Zone 2 & $13$ & Zone 3 \\
\bottomrule
   \end{tabular}   

    \end{minipage}\hfill
   \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
 \centering

 \caption{Second Table}
  \label{tab:second_table}

\medskip

 \begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
  \textbf{Start} & \textbf{Interval Time} & \textbf{Destination} \\
\midrule
Zone 1 & $483$ & Zone 2 \\
Zone 1 & $848$ & Zone 3  \\
Zone 1 & $121$ & Zone 4  \\
Zone 2 & $13$ & Zone 3 \\
  Zone 1 & $121$ & Zone 4  \\
Zone 2 & $13$ & Zone 3 \\
  Zone 1 & $121$ & Zone 4  \\
Zone 2 & $13$ & Zone 3 \\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}   
   \end{minipage}\hfill

    \end{table*}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, table* does not support [h] or [b].

Comment: You still do not have accepted a single answer, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer?r=SearchResults&s=5|42.1613 how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple, you need to add a \Rightarrow after your first table. Since I had time to do this, here it goes:

> ```
> \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
> \centering
> \caption{First Table}
> \label{tab:first_table}
>  \medskip
> \begin{tabular}{ccc}
> \toprule
> \textbf{Start} & \textbf{Interval Time} & \textbf{Destination} \\
> \midrule
> Zone 1 & $483$ & Zone 2 \\
> Zone 1 & $848$ & Zone 3  \\
> Zone 1 & $121$ & Zone 4  \\
> Zone 2 & $13$ & Zone 3 \\
> Zone 1 & $121$ & Zone 4  \\
> Zone 2 & $13$ & Zone 3 \\
> Zone 1 & $121$ & Zone 4  \\
> Zone 2 & $13$ & Zone 3 \\
> \bottomrule
> \end{tabular} 
> \end{minipage}
> $\Rightarrow$
> ```

Comment: it does not work. the second table comes below the first one

Comment: @Mohamed You need to make your minipages a bit smaller, e.g. `\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}`. This is why answers should always contain complete minimal working examples...

Comment: I did it. it is still the same

Comment: @marmot , I deleted the answer. How we can change the position of the arrow a little bit down

Comment: @Mohamed `... \hfill\raisbeox{-3em}{$\Rightarrow$}\hfill ... `. Could you do me a favor? Go back to all the answers you have received so far, and accept those which you found useful by clicking the check mark left of the corresponding answer. Thanks!

Comment: I did that now. You are welcome

Comment: @marmot the command raisbeox does not work

Comment: it's \raisebox .

Answer (score 5):

With `tikzmark`, compile twice.

The arrow is in the (vertical) middle of the tables, headers included. the vertical alignment could be changed if you want it only in the middle of the table content, headers excluded.

I also made some improvement in the table layout (but I don't think `>{$}c<{$}` for numbers is needed at all).

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \large
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{First Table}
            \label{tab:first_table}
            \tikzmarknode{A}{%contents
            \begin{tabular}{cCc}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
                & \textbf{Destination} 
                \\
                \midrule
                Zone 1 & 483 & Zone 2 \\
                Zone 1 & 848 & Zone 3  \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}   
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{Second Table}
            \label{tab:second_table}
            \tikzmarknode{B}{%contents
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
                & \textbf{Destination} 
                \\
                \midrule
                Zone 1 & 483 & Zone 2 \\
                Zone 1 & 848 & Zone 3  \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}   
        \end{minipage}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \path (A) -- node[draw, text width=3em, single arrow, thick, red]{} (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:* The previous solution needs v1.6 from 2018/10/18 of `tikzmark` (or newest).

For users with older versions, here is a pure TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \large
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{First Table}
            \label{tab:first_table}
            \tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](A){%contents
            \begin{tabular}{cCc}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
                & \textbf{Destination} 
                \\
                \midrule
                Zone 1 & 483 & Zone 2 \\
                Zone 1 & 848 & Zone 3  \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}}   
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{Second Table}
            \label{tab:second_table}
            \tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](B){%contents
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
                & \textbf{Destination} 
                \\
                \midrule
                Zone 1 & 483 & Zone 2 \\
                Zone 1 & 848 & Zone 3  \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}}   
        \end{minipage}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \path (A) -- node[draw, text width=3em, single arrow, thick, red]{} (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I compile your answer. my output is completely different than yours. there is letter "A" besides the first table and "B" beside the second table. Also, the arrow in not centered

Comment: @Mohamed Have you got an updated TeX distrubution? `tikzmarknode` is in the latest version of tikzmark, it does not work if you have a previous version.

Comment: I am using overleaf.

Comment: @Mohamed Overleaf has an old version. I'll update my answer to avoid tikzmark, wait a couple of hours, I have no time at the moment.

Comment: great. do u know how to make captions of tables as in my question?

Comment: @Mohamed To have the caption like in your question, just leave out `\usepackage{caption}`, see my renewed answer. By the way, you asked many questions but you have never accepted any answer, you should do it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer, see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer

Comment: Sorry, I did it now. You are welcome

Comment: Could you please tell me how can make the same two tables but below each other while maintaining the same arrow in the middle between them.

Comment: @Mohamed It's easy but it's better if you post another question, please!

Comment: How can I add a third table ?

Comment: @HebaMohsen Please ask a new question, with the link to this one, explain your problem with a minimal example. I'm sure someone will answer to you.