# How to edit this table format?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-arrows

How to change tables to be below each other like a column format with rotating the arrow 90

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \large
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{First Table}
            \label{tab:first_table}
            \tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](A){%contents
            \begin{tabular}{cCc}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
                & \textbf{Destination} 
                \\
                \midrule
                Zone 1 & 483 & Zone 2 \\
                Zone 1 & 848 & Zone 3  \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}}   
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{Second Table}
            \label{tab:second_table}
            \tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](B){%contents
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
                & \textbf{Destination} 
                \\
                \midrule
                Zone 1 & 483 & Zone 2 \\
                Zone 1 & 848 & Zone 3  \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}}   
        \end{minipage}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \path (A) -- node[draw, text width=3em, single arrow, thick, red]{} (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is from this nice answer: [How to add left arrow between two tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474801/how-to-add-left-arrow-between-two-tables/474811#474811)

Answer (score 2):

A minimal damage version could be

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \large
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{First Table}
            \label{tab:first_table}
            \tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](A){%contents
            \begin{tabular}{cCc}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
                & \textbf{Destination} 
                \\
                \midrule
                Zone 1 & 483 & Zone 2 \\
                Zone 1 & 848 & Zone 3  \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}}   
        \end{minipage}\\[2.5cm]
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{Second Table}
            \label{tab:second_table}
            \tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](B){%contents
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
                & \textbf{Destination} 
                \\
                \midrule
                Zone 1 & 483 & Zone 2 \\
                Zone 1 & 848 & Zone 3  \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                Zone 1 & 121 & Zone 4  \\
                Zone 2 & 13 & Zone 3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}}   
        \end{minipage}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \path (A) -- 
    node[pos=0.4,draw, text width=3em, single arrow, thick, red,rotate=-90]{} (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I came here to paste the code and found your code!!! lol

Comment: @Sigur Yes, that's advanced computing. The code is already there before you paste it. ;-)